# IOS Bluetooth LE Scanning Devices not adding to the uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, bluetooth

I would like to implement the bluetooth scanning and connect module for IOS using uitableview. When it comes to the execution, there has no items being added to the list. Would you please tell me what else I have to do to show the list of bluetooth devices with device name , uuid , and so on ?

For instance,
1. How to set my Array of object as the data source of the uitableview ? 
2. How to handle connection via Bluetooth between the devices when clicking ?

```
 _currentperipheral = peripheral; <--also fails at Thread 1 EXC_BREAKPOINT
```

The below is my console message

```
  2014-07-11 16:34:18.286 marker[6060:60b] Scanning started
2014-07-11 17:53:14.056 marker[6115:60b] Discovered WiT Power Meter at -67
```

The below is my model class:

```
@interface BTDevice : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *macAddress;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *macAddress;

- (NSString *)getName;
- (NSString *)getMacAddress;

- (void)setName:(NSString *)valueName;
- (void)setMacAddress:(NSString *)valueMacAddress;

@end
```

The below is my working :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pendingInit = YES;

    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    _currentperipheral=[[CBPeripheral alloc]init];
    _founddevice=FALSE;
    _foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _connectedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [_centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int idx=indexPath.row;
    BTSentCommandViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTSentCommandViewController"];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return  [_foundPeripherals count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_foundPeripherals count];
}



- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    // You should test all scenarios
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // Scan for devices

        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        NSLog(@"Scanning started");
    }
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

    if (_currentperipheral != peripheral) {
        // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
        _currentperipheral = peripheral;

        BTDevice *myDevice=[[BTDevice alloc] init];
        [myDevice setName: peripheral.name];

        NSString * macAddress =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , peripheral.RSSI];
        [myDevice setMacAddress: macAddress] ;

        [_foundPeripherals addObject:myDevice ] ;

         [self.tableView reloadData];   
        NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);
        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect");
    [self cleanup];
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"Connected");

    [_centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");

    peripheral.delegate = self;

    [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] forService:service];
    }
    // Discover other characteristics
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        return;
    }

    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([stringFromData isEqualToString:@"EOM"]) {


        [peripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }

    //[_data appendData:characteristic.value];
}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    if (![characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
        return;
    }

    if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
        NSLog(@"Notification began on %@", characteristic);
    } else {
        // Notification has stopped
        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    _foundPeripherals = nil;

    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
}

- (void)cleanup {

    // See if we are subscribed to a characteristic on the peripheral
    if (_currentperipheral.services != nil) {
        for (CBService *service in _currentperipheral.services) {
            if (service.characteristics != nil) {
                for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
                        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
                            [_currentperipheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:_currentperipheral];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"] ;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of code here, but generally it looks OK.  Two things do stand out however.  Your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is returning 0 - so there will be no content in your table.  You should have -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

I suggest that you just store the CBPeripheral in your data array.

Also, once you discover a peripheral and add it to your array you should inform the table view that the data source has been updated (This code assumes you have property `tableView` that holds a reference to your tableview ) -

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

    if (![_foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
        [_foundPeripherals addObject:myDevice ] ;

        [self.tableView reloadData];     // Tell the tableview that the data source has changed
    }

}
```

Then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` becomes -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"] ;


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }


    CBPeripheral *peripheral=[_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = peripheral.name; 
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

To connect to the peripheral when the table row is selected -

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"connectSegue" sender:[_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  //  This is a segue to your BTSentCommandViewController
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
     BTSentCommandViewController* sliderVC=( BTSentCommandViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
     sliderVC.centralManager=_centralManager;
     sliderVC.periperhal=_sender;

}
```

In your `BTSentCommandViewController` you can connect to the peripheral.  You should also set the `BTSentCommandViewController` instance as the peripherals delegate and implement all of the `CBPeripheralDelegate` methods there

Comment: I have used LightBlue and hence several devices are checked. As for my app, none of them even having followed your workings.

Comment: which part do i have to connect the bluetooth with method calling at  prepareForSegue ?

Comment: I would pass the CBPeripheral to your destination view controller in prepareForSegue and then connect it in `viewWillAppear` - but you probably  should remove all of the CoreBluetooth stuff out of the view controller and put it in a separate class - it will make your view controller implementations cleaner